# Merge all the beautification tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

There are the following 5 tags all for the purpose of making code beautiful. I suggest they are all made synonyms of [code-beautification](/questions/tagged/code-beautification).

[code-beautification](/questions/tagged/code-beautification) (57)
[beautification](/questions/tagged/beautification) (25)
[code-beautifier](/questions/tagged/code-beautifier) (17)
[beautifier](/questions/tagged/beautifier) (92)
[beautify](/questions/tagged/beautify) (23)

Answer (score -2):

Also add [prettify](/questions/tagged/prettify) and [pretty-print](/questions/tagged/pretty-print) to that list

Comment: `prettify` is the name of a Javascript module and `pretty-print` is a different concept so I would not recommend adding these.

Comment: @Kara: Where is there a canonical resource for "code beautification?" Googling for it comes up with the Prettyprint Wikipedia article.  The description in that article looks remarkably similar to the description in the Code Beautification tag wiki.  The [Beautification article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautification) is very generic.

Comment: @TheGrinch I could not find one either. The Prettyprint Wikipedia article seems much more broad than just source code. Maybe the tags should be synonymized to [code-formatting] instead.